# How to add the image as part of RSS feeds

Tags: rss

I have added the Title, Title link and description in RSS feeds. But unable to add the Image as part of the RSS feeds.

Please guide me how I can include the image within the  tag and display them in the RSS feeds.

Regards,
Gourav

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wrap your description in [CDATA comments](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) and insert the images as HTML [`<img>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) tags.

TechCrunch have examples in their feed that you could work from: http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch

For example from their current feed the first item about UK Entrepreneurs using the following description tag:

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[
        <img src="http://eu.techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/startupbritain.jpg" alt="" />
        This morning in London, the UK's answer to <a href="http://www.whitehouse.gov/issues/startup-america">
        Startup America</a> launches, titled - guess what? - <a href="http://www.startupbritain.org/">Startup Britain</a>.
        That similarity aside, the initiative has been put together by a number of existing UK entrepreneurs and 
        is not being backed by any government money, unlike the Obama initiative. Instead, we have here a 
        ground-up entrepreneur-led initiative which is seeing over 60 leading brands offer services to 
        up-and-coming startups in the UK. This is not specifically about tech startups - but it may well appeal to that sector. 

        The campaign is being launched by Prime Minister David Cameron, who is known to be very pro-enterprise. 
        The UK has 270,000 businesses that start up every year but many fail due to a lack of support. So in 
        effect the Startup Britain initiative is doing a few things much more differently. It's offering a 
        package of discounts and free trial on business services like insurance, broadband, advertising, 
        office space and more. The claim is that this amounts to over £1,500 in value for every startup 
        company in Britain. Startup Britain is a portal site to a package of these services. 
        <img alt="" 
             border="0" 
             src="http://stats.wordpress.com/b.gif?host=techcrunch.com" 
             width="1" height="1" />
    ]]>
</description>
```